# Single computer IP KVM - that does **not** use Java

Tags: kvm

I am looking for a single computer IP KVM that doesn't require Java on the client to connect.

I have a computer that needs to be in a location that isn't easy to get to, but occasionally I need to connect to the console during the update process.  In-band connection methos like ssh/vnc/etc are not enough I need to send keys to select a specific boot device.

I have an older IP KVM that uses Java, but the vendor is no longer really supporting it, and the jars have an expired signature.  It only works with Java 8, doesn't seemt to work with the Adoptopenjdk build, and Oracle recent license changes more or less make this an unusable piece of hardware.

- IP KVM
- VGA + USB connections to computer
- Cross platoform client connectivity from at least Linux/Windows.
- Looking for something less then $500 if possible.

I have been searching Google and various sites for IP KVMs and almost everything I am finding either doesn't provide enough details about what is required, or requires Java.

So to summarize I am tired with fighting making newer Java versions work with my older [IP-KVM](https://www.lantronix.com/products/lantronix-spider/). I want something that does not require java at all and preferably is and HTML5-based interface like why my newer Dells have on the latest iDRAC.

Answer (score 2):

"KVM over IP" products are essentially obsolete now.
Modern server-tier motherboards come with this functionality built into their remote management features, and it has been largely standardized across all systems for a given CPU brand.

On Intel boards you want the "V-Pro" or "AMT" feature set.
[KVM with Intel AMT](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-create-intel-active-management-technology-kvm-solutions)

You can use [Mesh Commander](https://www.meshcommander.com/) to connect to Intel AMT systems from an HTML client.

On AMD these features would be called "DASH". It seems like AMD DASH just uses VNC, so many HTML clients are available for that too.
[AMD Tools for DMTF DASH](https://developer.amd.com/tools-for-dmtf-dash/)

Comment: Thanks, I know modern servers have options. Yet, I have some legacy hardware and replacing the motherboard/computer to get built-in functionality is not an option.